# Floating Action Button not showing fully inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button, androiddesignsupport, android-coordinatorlayout

I am using FAB button along with RecyclerView in a Fragment. This Fragment is an instance of a TabViewPager. I am having a issue with the FAB button. I have placed the RecyclerView and the fab button inside a FrameLayout, where the FAB buttton is positioned bottom right. Now the problem that I am facing is the FAB button is not fully visible. Its half of the portion is hidden as shown in the screenshot below. Can any one help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

[image: FAB with RecyclerView inside FrameLayout]

**Note:** The FAB is aligning properly once it is scrolled. The problem arises only if it is ideal (before scrolling done).

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**tabviewpagerlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Note, I haven't used the new design library... However... It might be that the default is for the FAB to be OFF screen. Try removing the margin on it. When you scroll (up?) the FAB should appear. Scrolling down should remove it. This is so that the FAB doesn't get in the way of your last rows on your RecyclerView. In this case, there would be an accessibility function to make the FAB appear at will.

Comment: No actually when during scrolling it is working properly. But when it is in ideal mode the problem arises as like the screenshot attached above. It looks awkward.

Comment: Why don't try `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout`?

Comment: i tried with RelativeLayout also by assigning alignparent_bottom and alignparent_right="true". It is also helpless. Behaving like same. I think the problem is with CoordinatorLayout property

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should move your FAB inside the `CoordinatorLayout`.
Something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then you can add the RecyclerView inside the viewPager in this way:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new RecyclerViewFragment(), "Tab1");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where the RecyclerViewFragment layout is:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Yes I agree. But my requirement is to show the FAB inside the fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80135/discussion-between-chandru-and-gabriele-mariotti).

Comment: This solution has problems. I used this workaround, show the FAB in one fragment and hide it in another. But, then strange thing happens - when you scroll the list, the FAB re-appears itself. And why one should be bound to having the FAB in activity?

Answer (score 21):

It's not an acceptable solution to have to show/hide the FAB whatever tab is selected. I've tried every layout combination, but moving the FAB to the activity layout was the only solution that worked. But what if you need the button only in one tab? It's the only way that works now, but I'm expecting an update of the design library since this version is too buggy. Anyway, the bottom line is that the FAB must be a direct descendant to the CoordinatorLayout, so it doesn't get pushed down by the collapsing Toolbar...

Comment: Nog only that, but a nested CoordinatorLayout seems to not work either.

Answer (score 7):

1. I had same problem that the FloatingActionButton was completely invisible, and it was off the screen in the bottom. When I scroll down it comes up.
2. Also, the tabs were getting hidden when scrolled down but I wanted them to be visible always so I fixed it by removing   `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`.  Credits to JDev at [how to avoid hiding the tabs when scrolled down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778101/how-to-avoid-hiding-the-tabs-when-scrolled-down)
   This resolved the FloatingActionButton issue also, it's visible now.

Comment: @cgr This resolves the fab issue but now the toolbar does not scroll.

Answer (score 5):

I kind of did what Gabriele suggested with moving the FAB to the containing activity. Also you will need to update the FAB's color/clickListener in onTabSelected:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        setFloatingActionButtonForImagesTab();

    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(final TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:
            setFloatingActionButtonForImagesTab();
            break;
        case 1:
            setFloatingActionButtonForMusicTab();
            break;
        case 2:
            setFloatingActionButtonForVideoTab();
            break;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

and then in the setup function just set the color and click listener:

```
private void setFloatingActionButtonForImagesTab() {
    myViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    floatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.purple));
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "images", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        }
    });
}
```

Make note of the call to `setCurrentItem` above. It is required now that you are implementing `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener`.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you, but some addon point.

It is not that the button is pushed down, it's the whole fragment been pushed down. I haven't test it so far, but I imagine, if there is a way that enables you to see the size of the fragment page, you'll see it doesn't end at the bottom of the screen as it should be.

for possible solution, I'm think about adding a padding of size "?attr/actionBarSize" at the bottom.

I'll test this, and post back when finish

**update:**
As I used a border of 80 dp, get a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhreb.png) (I dont have 10 reputation to post a screen shot, wth)

**workaround:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            >
            <!--android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
            <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border"></LinearLayout>
            <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.derek.hianthy.mydiary.ui.BaseFragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/layout"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                />

        </FrameLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

notic app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" been taken out.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhyQG.png)

Answer (score 4):

It might be a bit late but to me the best option seemed to be create another fragment which contains the fragment with your content and the floating button. This code works very well in my application:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="domain.ItemsFragment">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.lucyapp.client.ItemFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_item_list" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me. Create a new class called CustomBehavior with the following code:

```
public class CustomBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<ViewPager> {

private int mActionBarHeight;

public CustomBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    init(context);
}

public CustomBehavior(Context context) {
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, ViewPager child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
}

public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, ViewPager child, View dependency) {
    offsetChildAsNeeded(parent, child, dependency);
    return false;
}

private void offsetChildAsNeeded(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
    if (child instanceof ViewPager) {
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) child;
        View list = viewPager.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        if (list != null) {
            final CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior =
                    ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) dependency.getLayoutParams()).getBehavior();
            if (behavior instanceof AppBarLayout.Behavior) {
                final AppBarLayout.Behavior ablBehavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) behavior;
                AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) dependency;
                ViewCompat.setTranslationY(list, ablBehavior.getTopAndBottomOffset()
                        + appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()
                        + mActionBarHeight);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now, assign the custom behavior class to viewpager widget in the xml file

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="yourpackage.CustomBehavior"
    />
```

Comment: I've upvoted this answer because I think it is the one closest to the right one. However, I've noticed that the first item of my recycler view starts behind the toolbar. As soon as I touch the list for scrolling, the CustomBehavior class kicks in and shows the first row in its due place.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue where the requirement was to show FAB in a fragment. What I did is just removed the line from toolbar

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

You can check my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >


        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot of toubles with this even in 2021. My fix

- place Floating Bar into main activity layout - so then it is displayed in whole app / all Fragments (I know) at CORRECT position.
- Then you can programatically hide it from Fragments you dont need.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issues with view pager 1st Fragment FAB buttons is showing below the screen and on scroll its show.
But after some findings I found that I have written

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

in ViewPager in CoordinatorLayout. So after removing this scroll behaviour FAB position issues is resolved.

Please check my Implementation working correctly :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/str_toolbar_subtittle"
                    android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/errorColor"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: In my case this didn't solve the problem. It looked ok until I've noticed that the first item of my list (the fragment in the viewpager contained a recycler view), was under the appbar.

Comment: This is not the solution bro. if we remove this "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
" the behavior action bar hiding behavior will be no more.