# Unable to hide fab button in arc menu programmatically. tried upload.hide(); Not able to figure out how to hide fab button

Tags: java, android

I am unable to hide fab button in arc menu programmatically.
I am using https://github.com/saurabharora90/MaterialArcMenu in my code .
how to hide fab used inside arc menu, programmatically in Java
I have already tried: but it's not working

```
upload.hide();
```

[Custom auto hide floatingActionButton behavior is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782192/custom-auto-hide-floatingactionbutton-behavior-is-not-working/42891292)
and
[FloatingActionButton doesn't hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269958/floatingactionbutton-doesnt-hide)

```
<com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu
    android:id="@+id/arcMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:menu_scr="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
    app:menu_open="arc_right">

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu>
```

Comment: you need to set upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the visibility of the view to `GONE`. In your code, you need to get a reference to the view you want to hide either using `findViewById` or if you use `Data Binding` in your project.

If your code is in `Java`, use

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

or in `Kotlin`, use

```
view.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: @rabinarayanbhukta I just made an update to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Manage the visibility of the view programatically.

```
    if (App.getInstance().getAllowVideoComments() == ACCOUNT_STATE_ENABLED) { 
         if (upload.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
               upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
         }else{
           upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
         }
    } else { 
      //Creating the Toast object 
     if (upload.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
          upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
 Toast.makeText(Createrelation.this, " Elite Editor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
```

Comment: if (App.getInstance().getAllowVideoComments() == ACCOUNT_STATE_ENABLED) {
upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                }
                    
        else {
            //Creating the Toast object

            upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(Create.this, " Elite Editor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } still not working

Comment: @rabinarayanbhukta please try updated answer.And please dont hide/show upload button in xml.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can remove from layout the fab button like this:

```
upload.visibility = View.GONE 

it will "remove" your fab button from the layout 
(will not take place some space in your layout and will not clickable)
```

or you can use:

```
upload.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

It will just hide your fab button but will still take place space on your 
layout and will still clickable.
```

Also, you can use a boolean value:

```
upload.isVisible = true/false 
it analogical:
upload.visibility = View.VISIBLE - true / upload.visibility = View.GONE - false.
```

Comment: tried upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);, still not working. i think is there any relation with arc menu so=ince for other fabbutton whic are not part of arc menu there setVisibility(View.GONE);is working

Comment: Please, try this: upload.isVisible = false

Comment: in java it is saying isVisible() cannot applied to FAB to booleean

Comment: I see u use a fab button from the outside library. I think u сan use it instead  your fab button to solve your problem: 

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
        ...
        ...
        ...
         </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton> - it is a fab button from official google library and then use above solutions to hide button.

Comment: i have one file where i am using

Comment: Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {.....  if App.getInstance().getAllowVideoComments() == ACCOUNT_STATE_DISABLED) {
            mFabButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } it is working but in file where i am having problem is ..here i am using Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (App.getInstance().getAllowVideoComments() == ACCOUNT_STATE_ENABLED) { ...}else {upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       is there any problem here

Comment: both are same library