# CoordinatorLayout overlapping

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

Have a look at the following layout. You will see, that the floating button is too far to the bottom. This is because the Toolbar and the Tabs are shown and the height of the ViewPager is wrong. So somehow I'm doing something wrong with the layout_height. But how can I fix that?

Remark: The ViewPager is the main content and it contains a fragment with a ListView and a Google Map V2 in the second tab.

[image: floating button too low]

That's the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager_list_views"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's the layout for the fragment in the first tab (the list):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
              android:id="@+id/preview_list"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
              android:orientation="vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_white_48dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Just to make sure; it's not a problem with the FAB. See this picture. It's a similar layout. A CoordinatorLayout with a ToolBar and a ViewPager which swipes through all detail-entries (therefore no tabs are needed). And again, the inner view seems to be too long (the same height as the ToolBar).

[image]

Comment: Please post the fragment layout that includes the FAB

Comment: Well clearly you can add margin to the bottom of the FAB and it will bring it up but as far as i know that should not be happening. What happens when you remove the src image and use the default?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the button and also not with it's image. The problem is the height of the container in which the FAB is positioned. The margin of the bottom is the same to the right and bottom. And If I turn off the toolbar, it looks fine.

Comment: I did not say there was anything wrong with it I am trying to help and exploring all possible solutions. You never really know what the problem is until you know the solution and that is why your here. If you think that is not the problem then do it and then you will know.

Comment: passible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731615/floating-action-button-not-showing-fully-inside-a-fragment)

Comment: thanks for the hint for the duplicate, but it's not. my FAB makes no sense in the activity because it would be visible in the map as well then. and it seems to be a problem with the CoordinatorLayout because I have another layout where the inner fragment is something else (no list view and no FAB) and part of that fragment is also overlapping the bottom. so must be CoordinateLayout or ToolBar problem :(

Comment: I added a picture if another view having the same problem but not FAB.

Comment: The problem is viewpager has match_parent. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I couldn't find any solution. Neither of the approaches worked. I ended up not using the CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: I have a similar problem, only using other views (like NestedScrollView) - if using CoordinatorLayout with a toolbar, the main content is moved down by the height of the toolbar and it doesn't fit the screen. The toolbar scrolling works. If you remove the CoordinatorLayout, everything is fit well into the screen size. Solutions like updating the lib version doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should use android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView and not ListView
2. Although you are already using android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView be 100% sure that you have declard `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'` in your build.gradle dependencies. I encountered the same issue where the viewpager overlaps the system buttons. I fixed it by simply adding this dependency.

Comment: RecyclerView is buggy as hell.

Comment: CoordinatorLayout will not work with ListView. I've been using RecyclerView in my projects and never really encountered bugs unless you are using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you what to be "coordinate" need to be **direct** child of `CoordinatorLayout`, Including the `AppBar`, `RecyclerView` (ListView in API21+ or other view support nested scroll is OK), or `FAB`, etc.

The reason why your `FAB` is offset out of screen, is that:

1. `ViewPager` has a `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`, the implement of this behavior will offset view when you scroll.
2. you put `FAB` inside `ViewPager`.

So when the offset of `ViewPager` changed, anything inside `ViewPager` will offset together (extra `CoordinatorLayout` has no help to change offset).

To fix this, don't use `CoordinatorLayout` outside `ViewPager`.

Or:

1. Put your `FAB` out of `ViewPager` so it won't scroll with `ViewPager`.
2. If the FAB only work with some of your page, `hide()` it when need.

BTW, there is very good App, [Cheesesquare Sample](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare), to demo the design library.