# Floating action button with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I using fragments in my app. I have base activity with hiding toolbar when content is scrolling. But is not working with this fragment. FAB is hiding ok but toolbar is not hiding  when i scrolling. FAB and list not fitting bottom. How to do that? Thx.

Sorry for my English please.

[image]

**Activity layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/app_nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Fragment layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_please_wait"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/adsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addAds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/adsList"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="sakh.com.utils.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_no_internet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_no_search_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating Action Button not showing fully inside a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731615/floating-action-button-not-showing-fully-inside-a-fragment)